# SQL query copied from views, does not work in Phpmyadmin

Tags: views, database

I created a simple view filtered by a specific day( I will switch this out for a variable when I use this on the website). The field is a CCK date field. The view works great. The SQL it generates is as follows: It just prints a list of titles from published nodes on a specific date (cck date field, not node date)

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
node.title AS node_title
FROM node node
LEFT JOIN content_field_event_date_time node_data_field_event_date_time ON node.vid = node_data_field_event_date_time.vid
WHERE (node.status = 1) AND(DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(node_data_field_event_date_time.field_event_date_time_value), SEC_TO_TIME(-25200)), '%Y-%m-%%d') = '2012-08-21')
```

I took this query and pasted it into the Query box in Phpmyadmin and it returns 0 rows. If I remove this part:

```
AND(DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(node_data_field_event_date_time.field_event_date_time_    value), SEC_TO_TIME(-25200)), '%Y-%m-%%d') = '2012-08-21')
```

and it returns all the rows excluding the date filtering (which is what I really need).

Eventually I want to do a count operation and use php to have this printed in a custom view field (or other places) to show the total events on a specific day.

Is there something specific I need to do with the formatting to make this query work in Phpmyadmin like it does in views? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: I should add I make sure there was no whitespace before or after any of the lines when I ran this query in Phpmyadmin

Comment: a quick look suggests you have two %'s before d where you need only one in '%Y-%m-%%d'

Comment: @Jimajamma - THANKS That's what I missed, the %%d was escaped for use with Drupal's db_query, I removed the extra % and it works great in phpmyadmin

Comment: been there, done that, got the t shirt, glad I could help out :)

Comment: @user1073319 -  Dumb question - why do you need _only_ need to escape the `%d` argument?  Why not `%m` or `%Y`?  I asked because I had this exact problem, but in reverse when using the `db_query`.  I ended up using %e for testing, but you now solved my problem.